# How exactly Wittgenstein "inspired two schools of thought [logical positivism/logical empiricism and analytic/linguistic movement/Cambridge School]"?

Tags: wittgenstein, analytic-philosophy, logical-positivism

In the page 527 of von Wright's *Ludwig Wittgenstein, A Biographical Sketch* in *The Philosophical Review, Vol. 64, No. 4 (Oct., 1955)*, he tells:

> It has been said that Wittgenstein inspired two important schools of thought, both of which he repudiated. The one is so-called logical positivism or logical empiricism, which played a prominent role during the decade immediately preceding the Second World War. The other is the so-called analytic or linguistic movement, sometimes also called the Cambridge School. It dominates the British philosophy of today and has spread over the entire Anglo-Saxon world and to the countries in which Anglo-Saxon influence is strong.
>
> It is true that the philosophy of Wittgenstein has been of great importance to both of these trends in contemporary thought: to the first, his early work Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus and discussions with some members of the Vienna Circle; to the second, besides the Tractatus, his lectures at Cambridge and also glimpses of the works which he did not publish in his lifetime. It is also partly true that Wittgenstein repudiated the results of his own influence. He did not participate in the world-wide discussion to which his thought had given rise.

So how exactly "Wittgenstein inspired two important schools of thought"?

- How was logical positivism/logical empiricism inspired by Wittgenstein?
- How was analytic/linguistic movement/Cambridge School inspired by Wittgenstein?

And what Wittgenstein "repudiated" in both of them?

Are there books by philosphers from both schools of thought in which we can read his influence being clearly claimed?

Comment: See IEP's entry : [Wittgenstein in History](https://www.iep.utm.edu/wittgens/#H10) for an overview. See also SEP's entry on [Wttgenstein](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/) with biblio.

Comment: This question is too broad. Vienna circle listed Wittgenstein as a  "leading representative" in their [Manifesto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Circle#The_Manifesto_(1929)), the influence on ordinary language philosophy is also common knowledge, see e.g. [Gellner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_language_philosophy#Criticism). Books are written about how.